# Is it safe to use 'chkdsk.exe' of the Windows 7 DVD on Windows XP? Repair mode is unable to output to log

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, chkdsk

Because it's newer and hopefully has fewer bugs, I'd like to run `chkdsk.exe` not from my Windows XP, but from the Windows 7 DVD. While I could simply boot from it, copying it to the hard drive would allow me to use the PC while `chkdsk.exe` is running.

The more important consideration, however, is that it gives `error 50` saying it was `unable to write the log file`, when it is run from repair mode. So the questions are:

1. How do I extract `chkdsk.exe` from the Windows 7 DVD?
   Update: extracted with 7z from install.wim.
2. Would `chkdsk.exe` from Windows 7 work well on Windows XP?
   Update: upon running it says it's not a valid win32 app. And it prints "Access is denied." to cmd line.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just wait for `chkdsk` to finish before using your computer? If you are ok with that, I'd suggest booting off the Windows 7 DVD and letting it run `chkdsk -r` on your drive that way to fix any potential errors before booting into XP.

Answer (score 1):

I ran chkdsk from a Windows 7 box on my external XP drive and it switched arround permissions rendering them hidden. 
May also have converted the drive to "RAW" format.

Kind of ugly.

If you can run chkdsk /f d: from an XP box with the problem drive mounted in an external enclosure, it's far better.

If win 7 is the only option, clone the drive first so you have an unmolested copy to fall back on if it doesn't work satisfactorily. Take the extra time. You may be grateful you did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the `chkdsk.exe` of Windows 7 is meant to be ran on Windows XP, please note that the architecture of the operating system has changed. Why don't you install Windows 7 virtually and obtain the `chkdsk.exe` from `C:\Windows\System32`?

Comment: You mean install it in a virtual machine? My hard drive isn't big enough and my RAM isn't either.

Comment: @user93200: Or extract it from the `.cab` files of Windows 7 hidden in one of the `.wim` files for which you need to install special tools, I guess it's much easier for you to run it in a virtual machine and send it to yourself...